# How to compare multiple result of SELECT to WHERE statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
UPDATE qTable SET statusId='Not Active' 
WHERE transactionId= (SELECT l.contractNo FROM custLeaseContract l 
                      WHERE l.statusId!='SIGNED')
```

the bold SELECT example of result is like this.

```
CN--TE-02172014M

CN-000-02152014

CN-111-02282013
```

is it possible to compare it one by one in every transactionId in qTable?

Comment: you may want to use `IN` example, `WHERE transactionId IN (SELECT l.contractNo...`

Answer (score 3):

You may try using the `IN` statement like this:

```
UPDATE qTable SET statusId='Not Active' 
WHERE transactionId IN (SELECT l.contractNo FROM custLeaseContract l 
                      WHERE l.statusId!='SIGNED')
```